# SQL Query use to parse out values from string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Question: 
How to parse out each U1 value in  a separate column using Big Query and column name should be u variable example u1, u2 etc.

Here is the string:

> dc_pre=CKX1m_vLoOUCFZUAXAodcgQKfw;gtm=2oda21;auiddc=*;u1=en;u10=undefined;u11=undefined;u12=undefined;u13=undefined;u14=undefined;u15=undefined;u16=undefined;u17=undefined;u18=undefined;u19=undefined;u2=bsd;u20=undefined;u21=undefined;u3=undefined;u4=us;u5=undefined;u6=undefined;u7=undefined;u8=undefined;u9=undefined;~oref=https://localhost.dell.com/premier/us/en/rc1295291/

Comment: Is the total number of possible u* fixed at 21 as in the example string?

Comment: Yes the total number of u is fixed to 21

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do this in three steps, but can be done in one query:

first.  split the entry:

```
SELECT 
   SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(0)] as dc_pre
  ,SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(1)] as dc_gtm
  ,SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(2)] as dc_gtm
  ...
from `database.dataset.table`
```

For each split, replace the text:

```
SELECT 
   EREPLACE(SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(0)], 'dc_pre=', '') as dc_pre
  ,EREPLACE(SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(1)], 'dc_gtm=', '') as dc_gtm
  ,EREPLACE(SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(2)], 'auiddc=', '') as auiddc
  ...
from `database.dataset.table`
```

Then you can convert undefineds to NULL if you like:

```
SELECT 
   EREPLACE(SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(0)], 'dc_pre=', '') as dc_pre
  ,EREPLACE(SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(1)], 'dc_gtm=', '') as dc_gtm
  ,CASE EREPLACE(SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(2)], 'auiddc=', '') WHEN 'undefined' then NULL else EREPLACE(SPLIT(<<FIELD>>, ';')[OFFSET(2)], 'auiddc=', '') end as auiddc
  ...
from `database.dataset.table`
```

I did this by memory, but as you can see the third example, is all three steps together.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! The final query does not necessary pass out all the u variables correctly.

Comment: @Pranav If it's working please upvote the answer and accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(line), 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u1=(\w+);') AS u1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u2=(\w+);') AS u2,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u3=(\w+);') AS u3,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u4=(\w+);') AS u4,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u5=(\w+);') AS u5,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u6=(\w+);') AS u6,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u7=(\w+);') AS u7,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u8=(\w+);') AS u8,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u9=(\w+);') AS u9,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u10=(\w+);') AS u10,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u11=(\w+);') AS u11,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u12=(\w+);') AS u12,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u13=(\w+);') AS u13,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u14=(\w+);') AS u14,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u15=(\w+);') AS u15,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u16=(\w+);') AS u16,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u17=(\w+);') AS u17,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u18=(\w+);') AS u18,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u19=(\w+);') AS u19,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u20=(\w+);') AS u20,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u21=(\w+);') AS u21
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

you can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'abc' other_cols, 'dc_pre=CKX1m_vLoOUCFZUAXAodcgQKfw;gtm=2oda21;auiddc=*;u1=en;u10=undefined;u11=undefined;u12=undefined;u13=undefined;u14=undefined;u15=undefined;u16=undefined;u17=undefined;u18=undefined;u19=undefined;u2=bsd;u20=undefined;u21=undefined;u3=undefined;u4=us;u5=undefined;u6=undefined;u7=undefined;u8=undefined;u9=undefined;~oref=https://localhost.dell.com/premier/us/en/rc1295291/' line UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'xyz', 'dc_pre=CKX1m_vLoOUCFZUAXAodcgQKfw;gtm=2oda21;auiddc=*;u1=en;u10=a;u11=b;u12=123;u13=undefined;u14=undefined;u15=undefined;u16=undefined;u17=undefined;u18=undefined;u19=undefined;u2=bsd;u20=undefined;u21=undefined;u3=undefined;u4=us;u5=undefined;u6=undefined;u7=undefined;u8=undefined;u9=undefined;~oref=https://localhost.dell.com/premier/us/en/rc1295291/' 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(line), 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u1=(\w+);') AS u1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u2=(\w+);') AS u2,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u3=(\w+);') AS u3,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u4=(\w+);') AS u4,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u5=(\w+);') AS u5,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u6=(\w+);') AS u6,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u7=(\w+);') AS u7,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u8=(\w+);') AS u8,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u9=(\w+);') AS u9,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u10=(\w+);') AS u10,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u11=(\w+);') AS u11,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u12=(\w+);') AS u12,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u13=(\w+);') AS u13,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u14=(\w+);') AS u14,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u15=(\w+);') AS u15,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u16=(\w+);') AS u16,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u17=(\w+);') AS u17,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u18=(\w+);') AS u18,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u19=(\w+);') AS u19,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u20=(\w+);') AS u20,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r';u21=(\w+);') AS u21
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row id  other_cols  u1  u2  u3  u4  u5  u6  u7  u8  u9  u10 u11 u12 u13 u14 u15 u16 u17 u18 u19 u20 u21  
1   1   abc en  bsd undefined   us  undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined    
2   2   xyz en  bsd undefined   us  undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   a   b   123 undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined
```

Comment: @Pranav - so now - you should accept one answer out of many given - the one you think best fit into what you expected to get :o)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you could use for this, if the data will be a predictable format, is to convert it to a JSON string then use JSON functions to extract the values.

For example:

```
WITH base_data AS 
(
   SELECT 
      CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('dc_pre=CKX1m_vLoOUCFZUAXAodcgQKfw;gtm=2oda21;auiddc=*;u1=en;u10=undefined;u11=undefined;u12=undefined;u13=undefined;u14=undefined;u15=undefined;u16=undefined;u17=undefined;u18=undefined;u19=undefined;u2=bsd;u20=undefined;u21=undefined;u3=undefined;u4=us;u5=undefined;u6=undefined;u7=undefined;u8=undefined;u9=undefined;~oref=https://localhost.dell.com/premier/us/en/rc1295291/', '=', '": "'), ';', '", "'), '~', ''), '"}') AS bd
) 
    SELECT 
      json_extract_scalar(bd, '$.dc_pre') as dc_pre
    , json_extract_scalar(bd, '$.gtm') as gtm
    , json_extract_scalar(bd, '$.auiddc') as auiddc
    , json_extract_scalar(bd, '$.u1') as u1
    , json_extract_scalar(bd, '$.u2') as u2
    , json_extract_scalar(bd, '$.u3') as u3
    -- etc...
    , json_extract_scalar(bd, '$.oref') as oref
    FROM base_data
```

Just replace the `dc_pre=CK...` string in the first statement with your actual column that contains the data. This has the advantage of being a single step process.